# Problems with my cucumber testing scenario

Tags: ruby, testing, hyperlink, cucumber, capybara

I have some problems with my cucumber testing scenario, where unfortunately I have an error:

```
When I follow "More about Star Wars"                        # features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:56

  no link with title, id or text 'More about Star Wars' found (Capybara::ElementNotFound)
  (eval):2:in `click_link'

  ./features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:57:in `/^(?:|I )follow "([^"]*)"$/'
  features/find_movie_with_same_director.feature:18:in `When I follow "More about Star Wars"'
```

I guess that it is connected with dynamic links to extract proper id.
Of course everything is working in browser and also when I test creating new record.

Details are added below

Could somebody to help me to find proper solution of my test scenario ??

In `app/views/movies/index.html.haml`:

```
 %tbody
- @movies.each do |movie|

  %tr
    %td= movie.title 
    %td= movie.rating
    %td= movie.release_date
    %td= movie.director
    %td= link_to "More about #{movie.title}", movie_path(movie)
    %td= movie_path(movie)
  =link_to 'Add new movie', new_movie_path
```

In `features/step_definition/web_steps.rb`:

```
When /^(?:|I )follow "([^"]*)"$/ do |link|
  click_link(link)
end
```

In my feature file:

```
Feature: search for movies by director

Scenario: find movie with the same director
 As a movie buff
 So that I can find movies with my favorite director
 I want to include and search on director information in movies I enter

Background: movies in database
  Given the following movies exist:
  | title        | rating | director     | release_date |
  | Star Wars    | PG     | George Lucas |   1977-05-25 |
  | Blade Runner | PG     | Ridley Scott |   1982-06-25 |
  | Alien        | R      |              |   1979-05-25 |
  | THX-1138     | R      | George Lucas |   1971-03-11 |

  Given I am on the home page
  When I follow "More about Star Wars"
  Then  I should be on the details page for "Star Wars"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Feature: search for movies by director

  As a movie buff
  So that I can find movies with my favorite director
  I want to include and search on director information in movies I enter

Background: movies in database
Given the following movies exist:
  | title        | rating | director     | release_date |
  | Star Wars    | PG     | George Lucas |   1977-05-25 |
  | Blade Runner | PG     | Ridley Scott |   1982-06-25 |
  | Alien        | R      |              |   1979-05-25 |
  | THX-1138     | R      | George Lucas |   1971-03-11 |
  | THX-1131     | G      | George Lucas |   1971-03-11 |

Scenario: find movie with same director
  Given I am on the RottenPotatoes home page
  And I check "ratings_PG"
  And I press "Refresh"
  When I follow "More about Star Wars"
```

Comment: Hi,
under https://github.com/khunia/hw3_rottenpotatoes.git i pushed my latest version of this projects.
Normally under Firefox everything is working but test steps don't

Comment: here is my email: khunia@gmail.com, give me your and i will sent you screens according my problem

Answer (score 1):

> When I follow "More about Star Wars"                        # features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:56
>
> no link with title, id or text 'More about Star Wars' found (Capybara::ElementNotFound)
>     (eval):2:in `click_link'
>
> ./features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:57:in `/^(?:|I )follow "([^"]*)"$/'
>     features/find_movie_with_same_director.feature:18:in`When I follow "More about Star Wars"'

Seems Capybara cannot find your link.
Try this step in your step definition on that scenario to click the link

```
    page.find('tr', text: "#{movie.title}") .click
```